# preg_replace multiple instances on 1 line?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, poker

I have text like this from poker software (I have highlighted the parts I need to replace).

> --- FLOP --- **[Jh 9h Ah]**
>   driverseati checks
>   darrington has 15 seconds left to act
>   darrington bets 100
>   InvisibleEnigma calls 100
>   driverseati folds
>   --- TURN --- **[Jh 9h Ah] [3c]**
>   darrington bets 200
>   InvisibleEnigma calls 200
>   --- RIVER --- **[Jh 9h Ah 3c] [Td]**
>
> Jh = Jack of hearts
>   9h = 9 of hearts
>   Ah = ace of hearts
>   3c = 3 of clubs

I want to replace the cards inside the square brackets with **IMAGES**.

So this line: --- TURN --- **[Jh 9h Ah] [3c]**
Needs to become: --- TURN --- jh.gif 9h.gif ah.gif 3c.gif

I can't figure out the preg_replace :( I can kind of figure it out for just a single card inside brackets (like the [3c]), but I'm stuck at replacing multiple instances on 1 line and some brackets having 3 cards and some brackets having 2, or 1 card.

This is what I have for a single card:

```
\[([AKQJakqj1-9]0?[DHSCdhsc])\]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am curious, why is the `0?` in your pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to do if you're looking for the square brackets (as you're finding out). If you don't try to match them and simply look for the card names, wherever they occur, then it's a cinch:

```
\b([AKQJakqj1-9]0?[DHSCdhsc])\b
```

The `\b` markers check for word boundaries. They ensure that the card name must be a distinct word, so `Ah` in `Ahead` won't match, for example.

Handling the square brackets quite complicated. Ideally you could use [lookahead and lookbehind assertions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php) to check for them, but there's an unfortunate restriction on lookbehind assertions that makes them unsuitable for the job:

> The contents of a lookbehind assertion are restricted such that all the strings it matches must have a fixed length.

So instead I came up with a double-replace solution using the `/e` flag to nest one `preg_replace` call inside of another.

```
preg_replace(
    '/\[(.*?)]/e',
    "preg_replace('/(\b[AKQJT1-9]0?[DHSC]\b)/i', '\\\$1.jpg', '$1')",
    $hh
);
```

The outer regex looks for square brackets and captures the insides. The inner regex looks for card names inside of that `$1` and turns them into images.

By the way, I added `T` to your pattern since 10♦ is typically written as `Td` in hand histories, and I added the `i` flag to make the searches case-insensitive.

Comment: That does work, but common words like "as" will be replaced too. So I need to tell regex to just look within brackets.

Comment: Do you have to match the lowercase versions? Will those ever appear in an automated hand history?

Comment: I also want to replace it in regular text (like blog posts, when a user says -- well, I was playing [ac][Kd] and lost -- meaning, playing Ace of clubs and King of Diamond). So I want to replace the pasted hand history logs as seen in the original post and user posted information.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "--- RIVER --- [Jh 9h Ah 3c] [Td]";

$CARD = "[akqjt1-9][dhsc]";
echo preg_replace(
  "/\[($CARD(?:\s+$CARD){0,4})\]/ie",
  "preg_replace('/\b$CARD\b/i', '\\\$0.gif', '\$1')",
  $string);
```

This code outputs:

```
--- RIVER --- Jh.gif 9h.gif Ah.gif 3c.gif Td.gif
```

---

Looks like John (narrowly!) beat me to it while I hacked away, although my code here is a bit more specific - it won't run the replacement on any string inside brackets, like `[as the world turns]`, it has to be a set of cards. I also limited it to 5 cards in brackets, although you could change this by simply adjusting the `{0,4}` in the match.

Answer (score 0):

```
function imageize($matches)
{
    $from = array('s','c','d','h','[',']');
    $to = array('s.gif','c.gif','d.gif','h.gif','','');
    return $matches[1] . str_replace($from, $to, strtolower($matches[2])) . $matches[3];
}

$str = preg_replace_callback('#([^\[\]]*?)((?: *\[[akqjtcsdh\d ]+\])+)([^\[\]]*?)#i', 'imageize', $str);
```